# Decision on number of clusters in Data Mining

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

When ever we want to cluster some data then It is required to give the number of cluster by user. Like K-Means algorithm we need to specify that how cluster are required.

My question is it possible that the algorithm decides itself that how cluster are feasible for particular data set.

Comment: This is research area.

Comment: @Umair is there any algorithm has suggested!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing number of clusters in k means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231717/choosing-number-of-clusters-in-k-means)

Comment: Consider using methods that do not need you to specify k. There are hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

There are several clustering algorithms that do not require a desired number of clusters as an input to the algorithm. An example of such an algorithm is the mean-shift clustering algorithm. However, you will need to specify a kernel as an input to the algorithm. This kernel selection (e.g., the size and shape of the kernel) will impact the number of clusters that you get as an output.

Some more information:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/TUZEL1/MeanShift.pdf
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert with that, but to answer to your question, yes there are methods to determine automatically the number of cluster for a kmeans for example.
It's quite complicated but given a dataset and a cluster method you can compute what is called gap statistic in order to estime the number of clusters.
If you are a R user, try to check clusGap and maxSE functions.